# How to override Mage/ImportExport/Block/Adminhtml/Export/Edit/Form

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, adminhtml, overrides, importexport

> app/code/local/Ti/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<modules>
    <Ti_Customer>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ti_Customer>
</modules>
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <Ti_Customer>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ti_Customer</module>
                <frontName>customer</frontName>
            </args>
        </Ti_Customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
      <blocks>
        <ti_customer>
            <class>Ti_Customer_Block</class>
        </ti_customer>
        <importexport>
            <rewrite>
                <export_edit_form>Ti_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form</export_edit_form>
            </rewrite>
        </importexport>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

> app/code/local/Ti/Customer/Block/Adminhtml/Export/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php

class Ti_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form extends Mage_ImportExport_Block_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form
{


 protected function _prepareForm()
{
   echo '000000000000000000';exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. app/code/local/Ti/Customer/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ti_Customer>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ti_Customer>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <customer>
        <class>Ti_Customer_Helper</class>
      </customer>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <customer>
        <class>Ti_Customer_Block</class>
      </customer>
            <importexport>
                <rewrite>
                    <adminhtml_export_edit_form>Ti_Customer_Block_ImportExport_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form</adminhtml_export_edit_form>
                </rewrite>
            </importexport>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

**1. app/code/local/Ti/Customer/Block/Adminhtml/Export/Edit/Form.php**

```
<?php
class Ti_Customer_Block_ImportExport_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form extends Mage_ImportExport_Block_Adminhtml_Export_Edit_Form
{
}
```